# How to check if a video or an audio stream is online or not in Vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, http-headers, video-streaming, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I wonder what is the parameter or the value to look for to check if a video or audio stream is online or not in vbscript ?

So this what i have tried as code until now, but, it give me a wrong results, because i have checked all those streams with VLC and they works 5/5, but with this script the second and the third stream give me as offline ??

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,URLArray,URL,ws,Msg,Data
Title = "Audio and Video Stream Checker"
URLArray = Array("https://5ac31d8a4c9af.streamlock.net/saheltv/_definst_/myStream/chunklist_w956788169.m3u8"_
,"http://aska.ru-hoster.com:8053/autodj"_
,"http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx")

Call ForceCScriptExecution()

For Each URL in URLArray
    wscript.echo "The stream " & URL & " is "& CheckOnline(URL) & vbCrlf & String(100,"-")
Next
'----------------------------------------------------
Function CheckOnline(URL)
    On Error Resume Next
    Const WHR_EnableRedirects = 6
    Dim h,AllResponseHeaders
    Set h = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    h.Option(WHR_EnableRedirects) = False 'disable redirects
    h.Open "HEAD", URL , False
    h.Send()
    AllResponseHeaders = h.GetAllResponseHeaders()
    wscript.echo AllResponseHeaders 
    If Err.number = 0 Then
        If h.status = 200 OR h.status = 201 OR h.status = 202 OR h.status = 203 OR h.status = 204 Then
            CheckOnline = "ONLINE"
        Else
            CheckOnline = "OFFLINE"
        End IF
    Else
        CheckOnline = "OFFLINE" & vbCrlf & Err.Description
        On Error Goto 0
    End IF
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------
Sub ForceCScriptExecution()
    Dim Arg, Str, cmd
    cmd = "CMD /K Title " & Title &" & color 0A & "
    If Not LCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\cscript.exe" Then
        For Each Arg In WScript.Arguments
            If InStr( Arg, " " ) Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
            Str = Str & " " & Arg
        Next
        CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ).Run _
           cmd & "cscript //nologo """ & _
            WScript.ScriptFullName & _
            """ " & Str
        WScript.Quit
    End If
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------
```

I got as response like this :

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 00:14:27 GMT
Content-Length: 232
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: WowzaStreamingEngine/4.7.8
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date, Server, Content-Type, Content-Length
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, User-Agent, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Range


The stream https://5ac31d8a4c9af.streamlock.net/saheltv/_definst_/myStream/chunklist_w956788169.m3u8 is ONLINE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 00:14:28 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Server: Icecast 2.4.2


The stream http://aska.ru-hoster.com:8053/autodj is OFFLINE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 00:14:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: https://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx
Server: nginx
X-Powered-By: PleskLin


The stream http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx is OFFLINE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What does this say `MsgBox URL & vbCrlf & All`, What is the status, what is the error number if one?

Comment: @Mark I just edited my question refer to your comment !

Comment: I went to the third one in IE with the HTTP debugger Fiddler (https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler) and it appears to be using a protocol called `icy` and the data is not coming in on HTTPS or HTTP.

Comment: So what are the statuses `h.status` for each?

Comment: @omegastripes `STATUS : 200    OK
https://5ac31d8a4c9af.streamlock.net/saheltv/_definst_/myStream/chunklist_w956788169.m3u8`
 `STATUS : 400    Bad Request http://aska.ru-hoster.com:8053/autodj` and `STATUS : 302    Found
http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx`

Comment: Seems request won't work for the second URL. You may try to untangle the third URL, by the next request to the URL from `location` header. Though I guess `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` (as well as other HTTP requests) are not fit well for that task due to connections variations. I would try to find some application which supports command line interface or ActiveX, and is able to determine if the stream alive, and will do all the job for you silently launched in background. That might be VLC or WMP, or something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible implementation with WMP:

```vb
Option Explicit

forceCScriptExecution "Audio and Video Stream Checker"
testStreams

Sub testStreams()

    Dim urls
    Dim sourceUrl
    Dim isOnline
    Dim mediaName
    Dim streamUrl

    urls = Array(_
        "https://5ac31d8a4c9af.streamlock.net/saheltv/_definst_/myStream/chunklist_w956788169.m3u8", _
        "http://aska.ru-hoster.com:8053/autodj", _
        "http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx" _
    )
    For Each sourceUrl In urls
        WScript.Echo ""
        WScript.Echo "sourceUrl " & sourceUrl
        WScript.Echo "Checking..."
        checkStreamOnline sourceUrl, 30, isOnline, mediaName, streamUrl
        WScript.Echo "isOnline " & isOnline
        WScript.Echo "mediaName " & mediaName
        WScript.Echo "streamUrl " & streamUrl
    Next

End Sub

Sub checkStreamOnline(sourceUrl, timeout, isOnline, mediaName, streamUrl)

    Dim wmp
    Dim isTimeout
    Dim t

    Set wmp = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
    wmp.settings.autostart = False
    wmp.url = sourceUrl
    wmp.settings.volume = 0
    wmp.controls.play
    t = DateAdd("s", timeout, Now)
    Do
        isOnline = wmp.playState = 3
        isTimeout = Now >= t
        WScript.Sleep 5
    Loop Until isOnline Or isTimeout
    mediaName = wmp.currentMedia.Name
    streamUrl = wmp.currentMedia.sourceUrl
    wmp.controls.stop

End Sub

Sub forceCScriptExecution(title)

    Dim arg, args, cmd

    cmd = "%comspec% /K Title " & title &" & color 0A & "
    If Not LCase(Right(WScript.FullName, 12)) = "\cscript.exe" Then
        For Each arg In WScript.Arguments
            If InStr(arg, " ") Then arg = """" & arg & """"
            args = args & " " & arg
        Next
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run _
           cmd & "cscript //nologo """ & _
            WScript.ScriptFullName & _
            """ " & args
        WScript.Quit
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The result is accurate ! Thank you man ! can we add the mute function to `wmp` object ?

Comment: Are you having any undesirable sound from stream playback? I have not noticed such while testing...

Comment: @Hackoo I added `wmp.settings.volume = 0` anyway, that should make checking fully silent.